# Resetting input text in redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

i found many questions on that topic but i couldnt find an example that was exactly like mine. Im trying to reset input values after clicking button add user. How to do that in redux with controlled components? 
My code: 
Component:

```
class Userlist extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
         data: this.props.ui.users
      }
    }


    render() {
      console.log(this.props)
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="text"
                 value={this.props.ui.inputName}
                 name="username"
                 onChange={(e) => this.props.uiActions.handleNameChange(e.target.value)}/>
          <input type="text" 
                value={this.props.ui.inputEmail}
                name="email"
                onChange={(e) => this.props.uiActions.handleEmailChange(e.target.value)}/>
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>LP</th>
            <th>USER</th>
            <th>E-MAIL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.props.ui.users.map((item, index) => {
        return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.email}</td>
                </tr>
        )
      })}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.uiActions.addUser(this.state.username)}>add</button>
      </table>
      </div>
      )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      uiActions: bindActionCreators(UI_ACTIONS, dispatch)
    };
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      ui: state.ui
    };
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Userlist);
```

My actions that handle input/adding user: 
https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/crudapp/blob/develop/src/actions/ui_actions.js

```
const initialState = { 
  users: [],
  name: '',
  email: '',
  inputName: undefined,
  inputEmail: undefined
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case UI_ACTIONS.SET_REPOS: 
    return { ...state, users: action.users };
  case UI_ACTIONS.ADD_USER:
    return {...state, users: action.users, inputName: '', inputEmail: '' };
  case UI_ACTIONS.UPDATE_NAME:
    return {...state, name: action.val };
  case UI_ACTIONS.UPDATE_EMAIL:
    return {...state, email: action.val};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

I know theres a problem with controlled/uncontrolled inputs. I want to reset input also in redux, cause even though input value dissapears after clicking buttons, the values are still there if you click it second time with same values. How to reset that properly? I want to do it right way. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using key for input fields because using key will reinitialize the form component as suggested in react docs, just try after reading this blog https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: will try after work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, controlled component means that you glue your form inputs (text input , password inputs, checkboxes and etc ...) to the state of your component and when submitting the form you are going to send that data by your **action creator** to redux.

you are not going to submit the form data by onChange event on every single change m **Dont't Do that** that is wrong.

for your case you need to have an action creator that uses the data from controlled component state and sends it to the redux:

```
... some code 

formsubmission() {

  const { username, password, email } = this.state
  const { sendFormData } = this.props

  const _data = {
    username,
    password,
    email,
    // and basically whatever data that you want to save to redux
  }

  const _resetData = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
    // and other data
  }

  // save to redux => based on your condition you can send the _resetData to reset form data on redux
  sendFormData(_data)  // or send _resetData

  // and finally you know that you can pass event to the function and reset the value of inputs by that
}

... some more code
```

by the way, that is my solution to this problem that i came along with by my experience in react, and i used it in some of my projects and it worked well so far, and i'm saying that it may not be the best solution , but it works!!! :)

Comment: I did what you wrote. Works, thank you. Can you tell me whats the easiest way to clean input after submission in that case?