# Clear input form after submitting in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Need to implement basic feature of resetting input form after the data has been submitted, it looks roughly like this, whenever i want to update or delete a record, i want the input form to clear out, i tried with setting the setNewUsername back to " " but the redux state of new username get changed to " " as well.

[image]

this is the code

```
import "./App.css";
import {useRef, useState} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addUser, deleteUser, updateUsername } from "./features/Users";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.users.value);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [newUsername, setNewUsername] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {""}
      <div className="addUser">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name..."
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch(
              addUser({
                id: userList[userList.length - 1].id + 1,
                name: name,
                username: username,
              })
            );
          }}
        >
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="displayUsers">
        {userList.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{user.name}</h1>
              <h1>{user.username}</h1>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="New Username..."
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setNewUsername(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch(
                    updateUsername({ id: user.id, username: newUsername })
                  );
                }}
              >
                Update Username
              </button>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch(deleteUser({ id: user.id }));
                }}
              >
                Delete User
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is the redux code, using redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { UsersData } from "../FakeData";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: { value: UsersData },
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      state.value.push(action.payload);
    },
    deleteUser: (state, action) => {
      state.value = state.value.filter((user) => user.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    updateUsername: (state, action) => {
      state.value.map((user) => {
        if (user.id === action.payload.id) {
          user.username = action.payload.username;
        }
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { addUser, deleteUser, updateUsername } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Should i clear the input field using useRef? I never used it before, though.

Comment: You probably want to make the two inputs controlled inputs (`value` attribute using local state) to accomplish that.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418150/resetting-input-text-in-redux

Answer (score 0):

After form submission you can reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another state like

```
const [userinputval, setUserInputVal] = useState("")
```

And when you can set the value of input & usrname like this

```
 <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          value={userinputval}
          onChange={(e) => { setUserInputVal(e.target.value); 
                             setNewUsername(e.target.value) }
        />
```

And then calling the function through button to clear userinputval and calling dispatch function both;

```
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setUserInputVal("");
            dispatch(
              addUser({
                id: userList[userList.length - 1].id + 1,
                name: name,
                username: username,
              })
            );
          
          }}
        >
```

Comment: it's kinda work, but when I typing some name in one input form, other input form also get's filled with the same value, although the result worked perfectly, it clears the form when I submit

Comment: Please check the `value` attribute of the other input. I think you kept that thing same for both the inputs.

Comment: oh, so for other input, i need to set different useState variable, not the userInputVal? thanks

Comment: Yes you can use another state variable